# Sound issue PJSIP if received a regular phone call

Tags: pjsip

When on a call VoIP and receive a regular mobile call, if I pick up the regular call the application using VoIP goes to the background and when I switch back to the VoIP call, there is no audio. The call is still in established state but the audio is not there.

Comment: Have you checked the state of the VoIP call once you switch to GSM call and then back to VoIP call? I believe the Call will be put on hold in such a scenario.